# Best way to auto update Poetry TOML versions

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, python-poetry, toml

I'm managing a repo which maintains common utilities, this repo has my common utils, jenkins file and all the dependencies are managed by Poetry so I've some TOML files to manage. We keep adding new utils as we go on.

```
.
├── Jenkinsfile
├── README.md
├── common_utils
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── aws.py
│   ├── sftp.py
├── pre-commit.yaml
├── poetry.lock
└── pyproject.toml
```

When I push my code to git, my Jenkinsfile packages it and publishes it to AWS code artifact. But everything time I push it, I've to manually update the TOML version in my local first before I push it to dev branch and then pull a new branch from dev to update the version again before pushing to master branch to update the version again otherwise I get a conflict on TOML version in code artifact.

I can't modify the Jenkins because even though it solves the conflict issue by updating the version, the version in the source code isn't modified, which means I still need to manually update all the versions manually. I'm not sure if pre-commit will help because I dont want to update the version every time I push to feature branch.

Is there a known way to handle this or is going with a release branch the only option?

Comment: Maybe you can use `poetry version patch` command in your jenkins pipeline. https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#version